# Should we use the word "Actually" before a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence, politeness, semantics

Someone asked to me about some particular information. I replied to the email like this:-

***Hi,
"Actually I was assigned the following task by my Manager"........***

Is it grammatically correct to start a word with actually?

Comment: Actually, yes, you should. It emphasizes the fact that your respondent is wrong and you are right.

Comment: Which dictionaries did you check in? There are relevant examples at [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/actually), where the hedging (softening) pragmatic connotation of 'actually' before a corrective is mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, although it's perfectly grammatical, it's a grossly overused (and misused) construction, and is generally discouraged for that reason.

In principle, it should be used to contrast the theoretical with the real (the actual) and essentially a synonym for "instead" or "in actuality". So, one might say,

> It was supposed to be an easy job. Actually, it sucked up an entire
>   day and the efforts of 3 people.

Its misuse arises from a common failure to state the theoretical part. While this is often acceptable in a given context, it is also often confusing. In addition, it is often used to assert the nature of reality in ways that are favorable to the speaker, but not necessarily apparent to anybody else.

"I've been criticized for sleeping with my best friend's underage sister. Actually, it was her idea. I'm a nice guy and the whole thing is overblown."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "actually" in sentence initial position is grammatical.  I can't tell you whether it is suitable stylistically, my sense is that it is rather informal, but its position in the sentence and its interpretation follow general principles of English grammar.

Since it is at the beginning of the clause and is not followed by a comma, it is probably a sentence adverb, which I would classify as a 1 (as opposed to performative type 0 adverbs, manner type 2 adverbs, or degree type 3 adverbs).  McCawley analyses such type 1 adverbs as sentence modifiers.  They concern the truth of the remainder of the sentence.  Other such adverbs are "possibly", "necessarily", "perhaps".  Like these other type 1 adverbs, "actually" cannot occur at the end of the clause it goes with unless there is an intonation break, usually written with a comma.

> "I was assigned the following task by my Manager, actually."
>    *"I was assigned the following task by my Manager actually."

In clause initial position with an intonation break,

> "Actually, I was assigned the following task by my Manager."

it may be interpretable as a type 0 performative adverb, in which case it says something about my authority for telling you of this assignment.